# Compress JPG image into RequestBody without creating a File

Tags: android, okhttp

I want to send a JPG file to my server with a size limit fixed to 500KB. This file should never be written to the phone storage (it contains confidential data).

My input is a byte array returned from the camera.

**For now this is what I am doing**

```
public Observable<User> uploadPicture(byte[] pictureBytes) {
    RequestBody pictureFormatted = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), pictureBytes);
    MultipartBody.Part picturePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("confidentialPicture", "confidentialPicture.jpg", pictureFormatted);

    return api.uploadPicture(picturePart);
}
```

How can I create my `RequestBody` with this size constraint ? I am ok with scaling down the image quality.

Comment: so if you want to scale down image quality then you are using `Bitmap.compress` method, right? if so, whats the problem?

Comment: @pskink if you are talking about [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)) it requires an OutputStream and I cannot find how to achieve this without an output file that will exist in the phone storage.

Comment: `How can I create my RequestBody with this size constraint ? `. Strange question. You would do that as you do now. But if `byte[] pictureBytes` does contain more then 500000 bytes you want to make them less.

Comment: use `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()

Comment: this is what I needed, but how can I chose the `compression` value so that the output will always be 500KB ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a bitmap

I just had to use a Bitmap with a ByteArrayOutputStream to compress my picture, but I could not find a way to get a precise size in output.

```
public static byte[] compressCapture(byte[] capture, int maxSizeKB) {

    // This should be different based on the original capture size
    int compression = 12;

    Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(capture, 0, capture.length);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compression, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}

public Observable<User> uploadPicture(byte[] pictureBytes) {
    RequestBody pictureFormatted = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), compressCapture(pictureBytes, 500));
    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("confidentialPicture", "confidentialPicture.jpg", pictureFormatted);

    return api.uploadPicture(picturePart);
}
```